# Does any version of Windows support uncompressing splitted archives natively?

Tags: windows, compression, zip, archiving

I mean, are multi-volume `.zip` archives, or maybe any other kind of archive format, natively supported without any third-party application like *7Zip* or *WinRAR*?

Comment: The very same question I have today. Thanks to your asking, I can stop searching and start suggesting 7Zip to my customer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box.  You have to go with 3rd party software to get the kind of functionality you're talking about.

I'm trying to find a MS reference for this, but so far no luck. Oh well, that's MS documentation for you.

Comment: Should be simply enough.  The native function that does exist has zero options to create a split archive thus it cannot extract one either.

Comment: *`You must install 3rd party software`* is not the "full truth". The free (FLOSS) 7-Zip tool does not need an installation.

Comment: @Wolf So true, I use plenty of apps myself which don't require installation. Updating the answer now.